# Can I set the inertia ratio using cv2.findContours?

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation

I have used `cv2.findContours` for pupil segmentation from a laptop camera and it works well in general. However, I fitted ellipses to the pupils, while as for the shape of a pupil I want them to be circles. Is there some possibility to set the inertia ratio like in SimpleBlobDetector? Do I need to use SimpleBlobDetector instead?

Comment: How about cv2.minEnclosingCircle()?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think minEnclosingCircle() wouldn't work in this case, it would just draw a circle bigger than the actual pupil as soon as the area is not perfectly round. I figured I would rather need the shorter axis of the ellipse, as in most cases the longer axis was just there because of some misclassified pixels.